# Codeplex SVN - Visual Studio - Upload mIssing Files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, codeplex

I have created a project in Visual Studio 2012. Have tried both tortoise SVN and another program but both of which are resulting into the same error.

Whenever i upload to codeplex, the pictures i have for the web 2.0 application do not get uploaded at all. I find this highly annoying and dont understand why. Any solutions?

Comment: Any error message? What where you doing exactly?

Comment: I found the solution. No errors, its just seems to drop all my pictures from the upload, as if it just wants to focus on the core files and nothing else. TortoiseSVN has an option, if you right click and click "view", it allows you to edit what you upload, so i uploaded it all from there.